# Mongorestore: createIndex error: Values in v:2 index key pattern cannot be of type object. Only numbers > 0, numbers < 0, and strings are allowed

Tags: linux, mongodb, macos, mongodump, mongorestore

I receive the following error when running `mongorestore` command with a large MongoDB database.

the machine where the backup was done:

```
db version v4.2.0
git version: a4b751dcf51dd249c5865812b390cfd1c0129c30
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1804
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

local machine version (where I execute `mongorestore`)

```
db version v4.0.10
git version: c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766
allocator: system
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Failed: prod.DeviceState: error creating indexes for prod.DeviceState: createIndex error: Values in v:2 index key pattern cannot be of type object. Only numbers > 0, numbers < 0, and strings are allowed.

Any help to solve this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the people who will come here in the future the issue was, I was using MongoDB 4.0 on the local and server was on 4.2:

Starting in version 4.2, mongodump uses Extended JSON v2.0 (Canonical) format for the metadata files. To parse these files for restore, use mongorestore version 4.2+ that supports Extended JSON v2.0 (Canonical or Relaxed mode) format. 
For details please see "Metadata Format" section on this : [docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump][1]

source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/250312/failed-to-restored-indexes-using-mongorestore-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Starting in version 4.2, mongodump uses Extended JSON v2.0 (Canonical) format for the metadata files. To parse these files for restore, use mongorestore version 4.2+ that supports Extended JSON v2.0 (Canonical or Relaxed mode) format.

> **Tip**
>   If general, use corresponding versions of mongodump and mongorestore.
>   That is, to restore data files created with a specific version of
>   mongodump, use the corresponding version of mongorestore.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#metadata-format

So, you need to execute mongorestore with `v4.2.0`

Or, try this (keep MongoDB backup)

1. Stop Mongod v4.2.0
2. Run Mongod v4.0.10 (if fail, go next trick)
3. mongodump database with v4.0.10

Other trick:

> mongodump uses Extended JSON v2.0 (Canonical) format for the metadata files

1. Start mongod v4.0.10
2. Create all collections + indexes
3. mongodump v4.0.10
4. Replace `metadata files .json` dump v4.2.0 with v4.0.10
5. mongoestore dump with v4.0.10

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, it's possible to adjust the dumped json using the following:

```
sed -i -E 's/\{"\$(\w+)":"([+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?)"\}/\2/g' XXX.metadata.json
```